# Passing strings[]'s as byte[]

Tags: java, python, networking, byte, inputstream

I'm working on a network in which my python script will communicate with my java application. The python script is passing a DataPacket (just a packet that holds some strings and a little other data) to the java server for processing. I know how to pack the information into a byte array, but how do I unpack it to be used as strings? What I've got so far is I have to parse the arrays of data in the packet and send it in bits and pieces.  Is this the only way to do this? Can I use ByteInputStream and if so how?

thanks
~Aedon

Comment: You need a byte array unpacking solution is java. You can remove the python tag as it is not of much relevance here. Also your application should not depend on getting the byte stream in bits and pieces. It is unreliable. It should depend on the structure of data that was packed from python script.

Comment: @pyfunc: it would be relevant to know how Python packs the strings into bytes though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that what you're doing is quite right, in that you're fragmenting your strings into separate packets. This could cause problems with multibyte strings.

However, you may wish to check out [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html). You can write into this, then convert to a String using `toString(enc)`, where `enc` is the encoding you've used in your Python to convert your strings into bytes in the first place.

Looking at your comment below, it appears you need some means to serialise in Python and deserialise in Java. Leaving aside solutions like XML serialisation, have you looked at possible solutions like [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) ?

Comment: Thank you for the response, for more clarification, the "packet" I'm sending is just a class called packet that holds the array of strings and a few integers. The only reason I wanted to fragment it is because I am unsure as how to convert the entire class into a byte array to send to the java server. How can I use Serializable passed into  to convert the class into bytes?